# System function in R times out?

Tags: r, system

Has anyone experienced problems with the system() function in R?
Short summary of my problems: I have several smaller R scripts which I ran from a "Master" script, using the system() function. For example, let's assume I have rscript1.R, rscript2.R, and rscript3.R. From the "Master script" I run the following commands:

```
system("Rscript rscript1.R", wait=TRUE)
system("Rscript rscript2.R", wait=TRUE)
system("Rscript rscript3.R", wait=TRUE)
```

It usually works quite well, and the three steps are executed one after the other. However, the process gets interrupted when one of the steps takes a long time (e.g. days). For example, step1 is clearly finished, but step2 is not starting. It looks like to command is "lost".
Has anybody experienced something similar?

Comment: Why not run `source("rscript1.R")`?

Comment: oh, because source is running the new scripts into the environment of the master script, and I want to keep them separated

Comment: You can pass `source` an environment where it should evaluate the parsed expressions.